# Redmine: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem “actionpack”

Tags: error-handling, compatibility, gem, version-control, redmine

I'm trying to configure plugin in redmine after getting a github link of the plugin it's installed successfully and these command running smoothly as:

```
sudo gem update
sudo gem install bundler
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem pristine bundler
```

but I'm getting this error when I write

```
sudo bundle update rake
```

after this command I'm getting the error and screenshot is attached.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":

In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):

```
actionpack (= 4.2.10)
```

In Gemfile:

```
rails (~> 4.2.8) was resolved to 4.2.10, which depends on
  actionpack (= 4.2.10)

rails-controller-testing (~> 1.0.4) was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 5.0.1.x)
```

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

I hope someone knows the solution to it.

[image: Screenshot of error message]